# Resources for learning Russian: Questions

Tags: discussion

In response to Alenanno's concern about keeping the original topic clean I suggest we post related questions here.

I don't like this idea though because the format of QnA doesn't work for discussions at all, but without anything better I will post it here.

So I don't mind the idea of having all the resource on the same page however it needs more work explaining what category is meant for what.

Like "Television". What is that supposed to be? Is "Videos" a better name for it? Can I post links to youtube under "Television"?

Addons is not clear either, what if I have an app that is not classified as an addon?

Etc.

Please provide more details explaining the purpose of each category.

Answer (score 1):

[Added explanations](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/833/71).

---

Those are perfectly legitimate questions.

On the Chinese SE, for "Television", I've seen people uploading free and legal channels so you could see Chinese TV channels in streaming.

For example, if there was a **free and legal** streaming for Первый Канал, you could add it there. By the way, this category will need constant monitoring. If a channel is down, remove it.

Add-ons are programs that you install in your browser, for example, dictionaries or other things that are going to be installed in your browser.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong. Do you suggest that we should have more sections in the resource question where users can post links to resources that don't fit present categories?

Comment: What I am saying is if you guys are certain about this categorizing thing it would be nice to get some guidance from you on which category is meant for what, because the names alone aren't explanatory enough.

Comment: Which is what the original question says, isn't it?

Comment: @v'-5o-1's73- Sure, we can add some explanation.

Comment: @v'-5o-1's73- I think that the categories are by no means fixed. If you have resources that do not fit in any of the categories, you can create your own with a name that you think is good. Otherwise, you can just post an answer called "Other resources" and put there anything that does not belong anywhere else.

Comment: @v'-5o-1's73- Before you add a category, though, please ask the community to see if it's the case to create a new one. This is a community-driven resource, so we must all contribute to it. Anyway, I've added some rough explanations to the categories.

Comment: @Alenanno I think that anyone can create anything, and the community can vote up, vote down, edit, etc. if it believes that the category is a bad one.

Comment: Ok, that works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Would more serious, scholarly resources omitted from that FAQ? For instance, Saint Petersburg State University has a website for Department of Linguistics, which has large [resources section](http://genlingnw.ru/resource/ReMain.htm), which includes things like dissertations, or even [whole textbooks on linguistics](http://www.genlingnw.ru/Staff/Kasevich/publicat/elementy.pdf). Would that be too advanced and beyond the scope of the FAQ?